# How much is a business worth?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

I am curious about the chance of buying a listed business.

Let's say I want to become the owner of Poste Italiane SpA.

Can I buy 50%+1 shares of [PST](https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/PST:IM) in order to become the owner?
How much will I pay for the shares?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I buy 50%+1 stocks of PST in order to become the owner?

It depends on what you mean by "become the owner". With 50% +1 of the outstanding shares you can control any shareholder vote (and get 50% of dividends etc.). There are still corporate governance laws and regulations in most countries, though, that may prevent you from drastic measures, like, say, completely liquidating the company. So you can't do *anything* but you effectively control the direction of the company.

> How much will I pay for the stocks?

The minimum cost would be half of the *market cap*, which is the number of outstanding shares times the current market price.  As of today that's just over 7 Billion EUR. But note than when you start buying large chunks of shares, you'll see the price rise as you go. So depending on how many willing sellers you find in the open market, you may pay much more than that once owners figure out what you're up to.

Comment: I'd also note in this particular case that the government of Italy currently owns ~65% of all shares because politically they still wanted to have control over the country's postal service.  You'd need to offer enough to convince the government to sell you a controlling interest which would be politically very unlikely.

Comment: @JustinCave Interesting - I didn't look into this company in particular to understand that. Certainly if there's a majority owner that has no interest in selling then owning a majority would be extremely costly.

Comment: "depending on how many willing sellers you find" - price going up due to lack of liquidity is also called "slippage".